# ATMEGA88PA Timet 1 Fast PWM Issue

Tags: embedded, avr, pwm

I'm working on a project for a customer in which we're using the chip mentioned in the title. The chip works as a fan motor driver, setting a duty cycle in accordance to a required tach count. One channel is utilizing timer 0 while another is utilizing timer 1. The fan driver on timer 0, which is set up on fast PWM mode, works perfectly every time in accordance to the required duty cycle. On channel 1 the fan driver looks like it works almost all the time, but sometimes it fails in strange occurrences, this is set up in fast PWM mode as well. When it does fail, the PWM output pin can only be set to zero percent duty cycle or 100 percent (or rather just on and off) and will not take in values between that (utilizing the ICR register to set the frequency, so

```
 ICR=MAIN_CLOCK_CPU/required_frequency
```

and `OCR1A` to set the duty cycle

```
OCR1A=(required_duty*ICR)/100)
```

). I have yet to have this fail on my bench top setup, but if I take the PCB out of the product back to my desk, reprogram it and then place it back in the product, it fails consistently (but the PCB will still work fine at my desk?).
The main clock frequency is set to 8MHz and the MCU is being powered by 3.3V. According to the data sheet, this is fine, and we shouldn't expect any strange behavior. I feel like I have exhausted all of my options as besides sometimes when the controller boots up it gets in this state, but it is not consistent. I'm just curious if others have experienced this issue before.
I feel like this can't be a firmware issue, due to the inconsistency I am seeing, but I'm not sure how the hardware could just simply not output a proper signal?

Comment: Do you have disabled interrupts during writing/reading ICR and OCR1A registers?

Comment: Yes I have protected writes around when I'm writing to those specific registers.

Comment: I may be able to post snippets of code later. And by protected writes I just mean disabling interrupts before writing to those specific registers

Comment: Try log TIMER1 control registers if fails happen to serial line.

Comment: I don't have enough Flash left on the MCU to implement serial logging. I'm pushing the 8K limit. Plus I have no way to access the lines as the QFN package is on a finalized PCB

Comment: Can you provide the initialization code? It looks like you have input capture enabled, so `ICR1` is updated. Please check input capture source (IPC1 pin or the analog comparator) and make sure its value does not change

Comment: @AterLux looks like you hit the nail on the head. We were de-initializing the peripheral every time we wanted a 0% duty cycle and re-initializing it after. This could cause some strange occurrences with ICR1! Being tested currently.